# Why does form submit produce AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter' in Django

Tags: python, django

I can't figure out why this won't work. My form displays perfectly, but when I press submit, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError at /cycles/new/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/cycles/new/
Django Version: 2.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Here are the corresponding file excerpts for reference.

#### models.py:

```
class Instructional_Cycle(models.Model):
    date_started = models.DateField(null=True)
    date_finished = models.DateField(null=True)
    standards = models.ManyToManyField(Standard, related_name="standards")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_started']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date_started) + ' to ' + str(self.date_finished)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('student_progress:cycle_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Standard(models.Model):

    subject = models.CharField(max_length=14, choices=subjects)
    grade_level = models.IntegerField(choices=gradeLevels)
    descriptor = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    description = models.TextField()
    essential_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["subject", "grade_level", "descriptor"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descriptor + ': ' + self.description[:100]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('student_progress:standard_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

#### views.py:

```
class CycleCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    model = Instructional_Cycle
    form_class = CycleForm
    template_name = 'cycle_new.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('student_progress:cycles')
    login_url = 'login'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet with extra items
        context['standards_list'] = Standard.objects.filter(essential_status=True)
        return context
```

#### forms.py:

```
class CycleForm(forms.Form):
    date_started = forms.DateField
    date_finished = forms.DateField
    standards = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=None)
```

I'm pretty sure the form is returning the values I want because in the traceback I can see this:

```
[...]
File "/Users/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/mastery_tracker-pGN-zVGo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
381.         self._clean_fields()

File "/Users/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/mastery_tracker-pGN-zVGo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_fields
399.                     value = field.clean(value)

File "/Users/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/mastery_tracker-pGN-zVGo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in clean
1293.         qs = self._check_values(value)

File "/Users/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/mastery_tracker-pGN-zVGo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _check_values
1318.                 self.queryset.filter(**{key: pk})

Exception Type: AttributeError at /cycles/new/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

And the local vars on the last step are:

```
key 'pk'
pk  '378'
self    <django.forms.models.ModelMultipleChoiceField object at 0x10c6fdcf8>
value   frozenset({'378', '800', '858'})
```

which are the primary keys for the records I selected to include in the MtM field. Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong. Can't find a similar question/answer after searching. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you wrote `queryset=None` in the `standards = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=None)`, what is the purpose of this? The `queryset` can *not* be `None`, it might be empty (for example with `Standard.objects.none()`, but not `None` itself.

Comment: I did that because I provided the query in the get_context_data function in views.py and use "{% for standard in standards_list %}" in the template to display the records from the query. If I put the query in forms.py as you suggested and use "{% for standard in form.standards &}" in the template, no records display. On a related note, if I put the query in both views and forms, after pressing submit, I don't get the error, but the record instance is NOT added/saved to my Instructional_Cycle model.

Comment: but how do you "inject" this queryset here in your form?

Comment: What if in your form you write `standards = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Standard.objects.filter(essential_status=True))`?

Comment: No, if I put that in forms.py, no records show up using: {% for standard in form.standards %} in the template.

Comment: but why do you "render" the form manually in the first place?

Comment: Wait, actually they do show up, but I can't access their sub-attributes such as standard.id, standard.subject, standard.grade_level, etc.

Comment: you *can* this is normally the `__str__` of the `Standard` model that is used.

Comment: Because I don't like the multiple selection widget when I let Django automatically render the form. So I'm manually creating a table containing the records to select from with the intention of adding js/jquery filtering/sorting.

Comment: I think you then might want to implement a widget, or change to an already existing one. The `ModelMultipleChoiceField` does not per se need to render that specific widget. You can take the original widget template and modify it such that it satisfies your needs.